# Postponing .then() calls on a Promise returned from an async JavaScript function until after multiple awaits have run inside the function

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I am using an asynchronous JavaScript http client to download & process some paged JSON data from an initial URI & subsequent page URIs.

Each JSON page includes the URI for the next page, if there are more pages.

Sometimes, I need to process all pages for an initial URI & its subsequent page URIs before progressing to the next completely new initial URI.

I'd prefer to use `await` calls to the async http client to handle the initial URI & all subsequent page URIs all within an single call to my own `async` function (named `f()`), calling `.then()` on the `Promise` returned from `f()` to process a second initial URI only after the first initial URI & all of its pages have been downloaded & processed, rather than having to pass a callback to `f()` that I must manually call at the end of `f()`.

e.g., can `f()` and/or the code that uses it below be modified such that `'uri2'` will only be processed after all pages of `'uri1'` have been processed without resorting to something like the manual callback mechanism in `g()`?

```js
async function f(initialPageUri) {
  let nextPageUri = initialPageUri
  while (nextPageUri) {
    const o = await getObjectFromJsonFromUri(nextPageUri)
    // do stuff with o
    nextPageUri = o.nextPageUri
  }
}

f('uri1').then(() => f('uri2'))

async function g(initialPageUri, then) {
  let nextPageUri = initialPageUri
  while (nextPageUri) {
    const o = await getObjectFromJsonFromUri(nextPageUri)
    // do stuff with o
    nextPageUri = o.nextPageUri
  }
  then()
}

g('uri1', () => g('uri2', () => {}))
```

Simplified logging from my real code: `<url letter> <page number or _ if no more pages>` in order of requesting:

```
A 1
A _
B 1
C 1
D 1
E 1
F 1
E _
D _
B 2
C _
F 2
B 3
F _
B _
```

Comment: This already looks good. The `while` with `await` inside won't resolve the function until the loop terminates. Not sure what's the issue here then.

Comment: How about a loop? Passing `['uri1', 'uri2']` etc. to `f` and having a higher-level loop above that while (a for...of, probably) would let you remove `g` entirely.

Comment: What is the problem with `f('uri1').then(() => f('uri2'))`? Are you claiming that `f('uri2')` gets executed before all of `f('uri1')` has been processed? If not, what is the issue?

Comment: `f('url2')` is indeed executed before all of `f('url1')` finishes.

Comment: @ZacAnger I'd prefer to not limit myself to a list of URIs as arguments to `f()` because, after all pages have been processed for the first URI, I might want to do something other than call `f()` with a different URI (e.g.,. `f('uri1').then(() => bar())`)

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution should work as-is.

Any `async` function returns a Promise by default. You can do `.then` on the result of the `async` function as you do in your first block of code with `f`.

Additionally, you can perform `await` on `async` functions to wait for the `Promise` to resolve before continuing. That is exactly what you do in your call to `getObjectFromJsonFromUri`.

Quick demo:

```js
function delay(msec) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, msec);
  });
}

let pages = 0;

async function getObjectFromJsonFromUri(uri) {
  console.log('requesting ', uri);
  await delay(1000);
  return {
    nextPageUri: pages-- > 0 ? `page${pages}` : null,
  };
}

async function f(initialPageUri) {
  pages = 2;  // simulate that each uri has 2 pages
  let nextPageUri = initialPageUri
  while (nextPageUri) {
    const output = await getObjectFromJsonFromUri(nextPageUri);
    // do stuff with output
    nextPageUri = output.nextPageUri
  }
}

f('uri1').then(() => f('uri2'));
```

Comment: `f('url2')` is executed before all the `awaits` of `f('url1')` finish. It seems to start running after the first `await`, but possibly before subsequent `await`s.

Comment: @XDR I've added a demo code to show how it works. Check if it helps, and let me know if you still have a problem.

Comment: @XDR: difficult to belive without a reproducible example. `f('url2')` should not be executed before, assuming this particular structure code of yours.

Comment: @XDR, try to add console logs around `getObjectFromJsonFromUri` to see that it is really called and that your code waits for it to return. Also, try to output the value returned by `getObjectFromJsonFromUri`. It could be that it returns a different structure than you expect.

Comment: I have seen output from my real code that follows this pattern that outputs the equivalent of requesting: uri1_page1, uri2_page1, uri1_page2, uri2_page2, uri1_page3, uri2_page3

Comment: Adding console logs everywhere and paying attention to timing and sequence will reveal the problem. `f2` cannot be executed before or at the same time as `f1` if each call to `getObjectFromJsonFromUri` takes any noticeable amount of time and `getObjectFromJsonFromUri` returns valid data. Also, logging before and after call to `getObjectFromJsonFromUri` should show that `await` really works and waits for `getObjectFromJsonFromUri` to finish. Maybe `getObjectFromJsonFromUri` is not async? Maybe it has another parameter such as `callback`?

Comment: I've appended simplified timing output from my real code to my question

Comment: @XDR how is it possible that your URIs don't go sequentially and jump from `B` to `D` and then back to `B`? Do you have multiple instances of this worker writing to the same log? What I see in the log is only possible if worker #1 picks a job with URI `B` and at the same time worker #2 picks a job with URI 'D', and then we see that `D` finishes before `B` while `B` continues for few more pages. It seems that there are few workers picking up jobs from the queue, or maybe the logic you've described above is somehow different from your prod.

Comment: @RAllen: It's running on node 20.2.0 as a command-line script (not as a persistent server). I haven't manually configured workers at all (this is the first time I've used node or await/async). I want to have multiple workers as a later part of my script can download & process data in parallel. The testing "log" is just `console.error()` redirected to a file, then URIs replaced by letters, with later log lines removed for brevity.

Comment: If you add `console.log` at the first and the last lines of your `f()` function, how log will look? Do you have `async` in the `f()` function declaration, and do you have `await` before the `getObjectFromJsonFromUri` call? And most importantly, how the code that calls `f()` function look right now? It cannot be hardcoded `f('A').then(() => f('B'));` if we see what we see in the log.

Comment: @RAllen I've been simplifying my code, ripping out functional & organizational parts to get closer to the `await` essentials without other stuffing the way. I now get the correct request order after having replaced all callback arguments to `then()` that were to a wrapper function to just call the underlying function. I need to postpone further work on this for maybe 8 hours, but I imagine that I should be able to figure out why the wrapper function is causing problems. I'll reply later with the solution, or with questions if the solution eludes me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RAllen The wrapper function didn't return the `Promise` from the fetch code that downloads & processes the JSON. Once that function returned the `Promise`, everything ordered correctly. Thanks for the help.